# HDD Working very slow

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I had an external HDD. It's USB connection socket along-with the microchip attached was damaged. I removed HDD case and found an Seagate Momentus 2.5" HDD. I then tried to use it as internal. It worked, but copying data into HDD is now very very slow. The copy speed has dropped significantly. I don't know why ? What can be the cause ?

[image]

Comment: Copy speed depends highly on the filesystem used and the speed of the target Drive. If using windows, try http://www.hdtune.com/download.html and give us the results

Comment: @Kwaio Done ! File Benchmark report added !

Comment: The first graph shows indeed strange behaviour...but i'm no expert. Hope someone more qualified can.

Comment: Although I cannot answer your question, I would HIGHLY recommend backing up all of your important data on the HD in case it fails or needs to be formatted.

Comment: I've kept data safe in another HDD. But all benchmarks are like above one, strange :(

Answer (score -1):

It looks like damaged HDD (I see many like that in my work). Check SMART (with gsmartcontrol or hddscan). Maybe USB connector was damaged by drop or hit disk?

Comment: This answer would be better served as a comment rather then an answer.

Comment: I don't have right to make a comment

Comment: Earn the right.